# Alternative to Limb Lengthening

Tags: nerves, stem-cells, cosmetics

Some of you who are familiar with the current surgery for limb lengthening know the steps ([link](https://www.limblength.org/treatments/limb-lengthening-the-process/#:%7E:text=lengthened%20too%20quickly%3F-,Even%20though%20the%20typical%20rate%20of%20lengthening%20is%201%20mm,slower%20in%20smokers%20and%20diabetics.)):

- Break bones
- Insert rod
- Await callus formation
- Lengthen
- Consolidate

The issue is during the lengthening phase whereby the speed needs the be faster than bone healing (for it not to consolidate and become immobile) and not too fast for soft tissue growth. During our natural growth spurts, we grow 3 inches in like 9 months, while here it is done in 3 months. Does it mean if we prolonged the synthetic lengthening, it would have no complications on the soft tissue?

What if instead of allowing a callus to form, we leave a gap (a non union) that we fill with stem cells during lengthening, but not too much to leave the cavity. That way we can lengthen at a normal puberty speed, then close the gap with more stem cells during consolidation phase. Why can't this work?

Comment: Hi Orthoguy, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.